# Better way to conditionally access values

Tags: javascript

I'm wondering if there's a better way to achieve this:

```js
const string = a < b ? 'value 1' : a > c ? 'value 2' : 'value 3'
```

I would do something like this, but it wouldn't work with conditions.

```js
const string = {
  0: 'value 1',
  1: 'value 2',
}[ ? ] || 'value 3'
```

> I'm convinced there are better ways to do this and I just haven't found it yet.
> Thanks in advance.

Comment: The ternaries are just fine and probably the best way to achieve this. They're more readable with grouping parenthesis or multiline indentation, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's certainly some boolean and/or arithmetic logic to make an expression work that could be placed in the `?`, but this will only obfuscate the behaviour.

I would recommend to use indentation to make the logic clear and readable:

```
const string = a < b ? 'value 1'
             : a > c ? 'value 2'
             : 'value 3';
```

```
const string = a < b ? 'value 1' :
               a > c ? 'value 2' :
               'value 3';
```

Answer (score 0):

While your variant on my opinion is the clearest one, here is another similar way of doing this

```js
// Set values
const a = 4,
      b = 3,
      c = 5;

// Do inline conditional check
const string = a<b &&'value 1' ||
               a>c &&'value 2' ||
               'value 3';

// Log
console.log(string)
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless your are the only person keeping this code why not go to the most readable way despite the number of lines?

```
const string = 'value3'

if( a < b ) string = 'value1'
else if( a > c ) string = 'value2'
```